# How can I make XPathFactory newInstance fail in Java?

Tags: java, classloader, system-properties

Documentation for XPathFactory.newInstance(String uri) is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String)).

I am trying to make this fail like this:

```
println(System.getProperty("DEFAULT_PROPERTY_NAME"));
System.setProperty("DEFAULT_PROPERTY_NAME", "dummy");
println(System.getProperty("DEFAULT_PROPERTY_NAME"));
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
println(xPathFactory.getClass());
```

The output I am getting is :

```
null
dummy
class org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl
```

I am expecting that the ClassLoader will fail due to the bullet point:

> If the system property DEFAULT_PROPERTY_NAME + ":uri" is present,
>   where uri is the parameter to this method, then its value is read as a
>   class name. The method will try to create a new instance of this class
>   by using the class loader, and returns it if it is successfully
>   created.

but that is not the case and I am obviously missing something.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, do you set the property `DEFAULT_PROPERTY_NAME + ":uri"` ?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Sorry, I do not understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting that the ClassLoader will fail due to the bullet point:

This bullet point refers to method:

```
public static final XPathFactory newInstance(String uri)
```

But you are calling:

```
public static final XPathFactory newInstance()
```

which states:

> This method is functionally equivalent to:
>
> newInstance(DEFAULT_OBJECT_MODEL_URI)
>
> Since the implementation for the W3C DOM is always available, this method will never fail.

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
System.setProperty("DEFAULT_PROPERTY_NAME", "dummy");
```

to

```
System.setProperty(XPathFactory.DEFAULT_OBJECT_MODEL_URI, "dummy");
```